# Find $\sum^{30}_{k=7}(\sqrt{k - 4} - \sqrt{k - 3})$ without explicitly calculating the 24 complements

Tags: calculus, summation, transformation

Is it possible to find $\sum^{30}_{k=7}(\sqrt{k - 4} - \sqrt{k - 3})$ without explicitly calculating the 24 complements ?

I have this task in a text book and it doesn't provide any equivalent example, which makes me think that the only way to solve it is by explicitly calculating the complements ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Try writing down the first few terms.

Comment: I'm almost certain that your textbook has equivalent examples, but you might just not recognize what concept is involved. Highlight to reveal the concept: $\color{white}{\text{telescoping series}}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

We have that

$$\sum^{30}_{k=7}(\sqrt{k - 4} - \sqrt{k - 3})=\sum^{30}_{k=7}\sqrt{k - 4} - \sum^{30}_{k=7}\sqrt{k - 3}=\sum^{30}_{k=7}\sqrt{k - 4} - \sum^{31}_{j=8}\sqrt{j - 4}$$

Comment: thank you to me the answer is totally clear

Comment: @DmitryKoroliov As suggested in the comments, you can also obtain the result term by term noting that the sum telescopes and almost all terms cancels out.